# How to solve the value error received while working with this dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, key-value

I have a dataframe from which the columns are grouped as:

```
{(a, b, c): [('d', e, f)]}
```

with this command:

```
dct = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])[['d','e','f']].apply(
            lambda g: list(map(tuple, g.values.tolist()))).to_dict()
```

After this, I apply:

```
dct = {k: dict(v) for k,v in dct.items()}
```

which gives me the following error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

I want to make a dictionary in following format.

```
{(a,b,c):{d:(e,f)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
dct = {k: {v[0][0]:v[0][1:]} for k,v in dct.items()}
```

Comment: @MushahidHussain Can you share the output of `dct`?

Comment: Do you mean the output where I am grouping the columns?

Comment: If that's the case, it looks like this: {(a, b, c): [('d', 'e', 'f')]}

Comment: Try this: `dct = {k: {v[0][0]:v[0][1:]} for k,v in dct.items()}`